# Creating online survey with randomization, partial completion and data importing

Tags: google-forms, survey, surveymonkey, limesurvey

I'm trying to make a relatively simple online survey that contains ~300 pages. Each page has a different text and couple of radio buttons or a slider. I need following features:

(1) Page order is randomized each time the survey is started (only one URL to the survey)

(2) User can stop responding at any time (this is expected), but the responses are automatically saved online after each page (no need to submit)

(3) Form questions can be uploaded as sheet/text format and are used to generate those 300 pages automatically (via scripting), no tedious manual work required if questions are updated at some point.

So far I haven't been able to find a service that would support all three. Service does not need to be free, but price must be reasonable (up to ~100$ or so). For example, Google Forms can easily do (3), but not (1) or (2). Popular online surveys services can do (1) and (2), but not (3).

Is there any online services that can do all three or is my only options to grab some code (e.g., LimeSurvey) and do it myself the hard way?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Denis Chenu, LimeSurvey does it all! Thanks!

For those interested, all you need to do is to make a free LimeSurvey Pro account (hosted) and a small template survey manually. Take your time and set it right. Then download your small survey as tab-separated .txt format and figure out how the survey is encoded (it's pretty straightforward). For a simple survey like mine, I only needed to repeat the same questions with modified text strings. This process is easy to automatize (e.g., Python) and your code can make a new .txt file with hundreds of questions. Then you import that into LimeSurvey as a new survey and your are done.

However, to execute the actual survey (with over 25 responses), you need a paid licence or you can install LimeSurvey to your own server (this is my next step).

Answer (score 0):

LimeSurvey do 1+2+3 out of the box , see https://manual.limesurvey.org/Tab_Separated_Value_survey_structure for 3 and https://manual.limesurvey.org/Question_groups_-_introduction#Question_group_randomization for 1 (no need extra script). 2 is always included.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) SurveyMonkey has [page randomization](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-is-Page-Randomization)

For 2) That's just normal behaviour, pages are submitted one at a time.

For 3) SurveyMonkey has the ability to [copy/paste questions](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Copy-Paste-Questions) and also has a [public API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-pages-and-questions) that may help you do option 3.

Hope that helps.